# Problema com funções

Tags: c#, sql

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma `view` no banco que faz um `group by`, e tenho uma outra tabela `GraficoCor`, quero fazer com que cada vez que o `While` da primeira função fizer um incremento, ele passe o valor do contador para a variável `IdCor` da segunda função, a segunda função fará a consulta tendo como referencia o valor do `IdCor` retornando a cor em hexadecimal para a primeira função. 
Como faria isso?

Função `GetFaturamentoIVEL`

```
public static FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[] GetFaturamentoIVEL(string Operacao, Connection Cn)
        {
            var RsFaturamento = new Recordset();
            int Cont = 0;
            try
            {
                RsFaturamento.Open(String.Format("SELECT Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing, SUM(ValorNF)AS ValorTotal FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL WHERE TradeMarketing = 0  and AnoMes = '2016/04' GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) ASC", Operacao), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                var ArrayRetorno = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[RsFaturamento.RecordCount];
                while (!RsFaturamento.EOF)
                {
                    FatoFaturamentoIVELBO Faturamento = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO();
                    Faturamento.Operacao = RsFaturamento.Fields["Operacao"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.AnoMes = RsFaturamento.Fields["AnoMes"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.ValorNF = decimal.Parse(RsFaturamento.Fields["ValorTotal"].Value.ToString());
                    ArrayRetorno[Cont] = Faturamento;
                    Cont++;
                    RsFaturamento.MoveNext();
                }
                RsFaturamento.Close();
                return ArrayRetorno;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Função `GetCor`

```
public  static FatoFaturamentoIVELBO GetCor(int IdCor, Connection Cn)
        {
            var Cor = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO();
            var RsCor = new Recordset();
            try
            {
                RsCor.Open(String.Format("SELECT IdCor, CodHex from dbo.GraficoCor  where IdCor = " + IdCor), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                if (!RsCor.EOF)
                {
                    Cor.CodHex = RsCor.Fields["CodHex"].Value.ToString();
                }
                return Cor;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: De novo? Me dei o trabalho de tentar responder na outra pergunta e você a apagou! Não seria mais fácil tentar ser mais específico na sua dúvida do que ficar apagando as perguntas e criando novas?

Comment: Desculpe, achei que a anterior estava mal formulada. Mas consegui, vou postar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com a ajuda do @jbueno

```
public static FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[] GetFaturamentoIVEL(string Operacao, Connection Cn)
        {

            var RsFaturamento = new Recordset();
            int Cont = 0;
            int CountCor = 0;
            try
            {
                RsFaturamento.Open(String.Format("SELECT Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing, SUM(ValorNF)AS ValorTotal FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL WHERE TradeMarketing = 0  and AnoMes = '2016/04' GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) ASC", Operacao), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                var ArrayRetorno = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[RsFaturamento.RecordCount];
                while (!RsFaturamento.EOF)
                {
                    FatoFaturamentoIVELBO Faturamento = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO();
                    Faturamento.Operacao = RsFaturamento.Fields["Operacao"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.AnoMes = RsFaturamento.Fields["AnoMes"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.ValorNF = decimal.Parse(RsFaturamento.Fields["ValorTotal"].Value.ToString());
                    Faturamento.CodHex = GetCor(CountCor++, ref Cn);

                    ArrayRetorno[Cont] = Faturamento;

                    Cont++;
                    RsFaturamento.MoveNext();
                }

                RsFaturamento.Close();

                return ArrayRetorno;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }





        private static string GetCor(int IdCor, ref Connection Cn)
        {
            var RsCor = new Recordset();

            try
            {
                RsCor.Open(String.Format("SELECT IdCor, CodHex from dbo.GraficoCor  where IdCor = {0}", IdCor), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                if (!RsCor.EOF)
                {
                    return RsCor.Fields["CodHex"].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //nao encontrou a cor vc faz o que?????? retorna pink! uhahuahuhuahuahuahua
                    return "#FFFFFF";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```